# DSP board TMDX5505EZDSP potentiometers and switches

Tags: dsp

I have to do a project for school that is an audio effects processor but I'm not experienced with dsp. I'm using the Texas Instruments TMDX5505EZDSP. I've programmed some audio effects based on some example codes, but now I would like to set some of the variables with some potentiometers and switches. How do I read the value of a potentiometer/switch and use it in real time as a variable of the program? Is this even possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally you connect the pot output to a A/D input.  The two ends of the pot go to the same power and ground that the microcontroller is connected to.  The wiper is connected to the A/D input.

The pot will produce a voltage anywhere from ground to power.  It should be possible to set up the A/D so that this range is full scale.  The pot position therefore sets the digital value coming out of the A/D.

The rest is software to do something with this digital value representing the pot setting.

One advantage of connection the pot ends to the same voltages as the A/D references is that the result becomes *ratiometric*.  Since both the pot input and the A/D conversion range come from the same voltages, these voltages cancel out.  You don't need a accurate reference or power supply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the 5505 only have one jack input to the A/D converter. I need to connect at least 3 potentiometers and 2 switches.